# Meaning of "to live one's own bit"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms

Speaking of Richard Henry Dana, at the end of his study, D. H. Lawrence states:

> Dana *lived his bit* in two years, and drummed out the rest.

Could we say that "lived his bit" is akin to "sow (one's) wild oats"?

Comment: It means he was only truly alive for those 2 years. For his remaining years on Earth, he "phoned it in". Lived a mundane and unremarkable life.  "Sow one's oats" is usually reserved for procreation or promiscuity, but if you want to take a broader reading of "lived life to its fullest, travelling and *doing*", then you could say it applies. But the reality is it's so associated with the sex meaning, people would probably misunderstand you if you used it that way.

Comment: For reference the quote is from DH Lawrence's Studies in Classic American Literature, Ch 9, online here: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Studies_in_Classic_American_Literature/Chapter_9

Comment: It's another way of saying what today might be: did his thing

Answer (score 1):

From the idiom **do one's bit**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/do+(one%27s)+bit)

> to make an individual contribution toward an overall effort.

and

**bit**: small part of something.  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bit)

As in:

> Dana lived his bit ( the short but most 'contributing' part of his
>   life) in two years, and drummed out the rest.

I do not sense sexuality in this sense of the use of 'bit'.

Comment: "Sow one's wild oats" usually has a sexual element but not always (unless lexicographers are being modest): [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sow-wild-oats) "has a period of his life when he does a lot of exciting things and has a lot of sexual relationships", [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-sow-your-wild-oats) "behave in a rather uncontrolled way, especially by having a lot of sexual relationships." Although this makes the question hard to interpret.